# Multi-label classification vs multi-model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks

I'm working on classification of `delay / (no delay) / negative delay` for airplanes ( 2 or 3 labels). I'm also playing with idea to model no delay, delay and large delay.

I noticed that there are cases where I can quite well train `neural network` form [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) that it makes little mistake for either delay or negative delay in the training set. From my little experience my gut is telling me it is nonsense to use two/three models for each label. What if they disagree on the label? Could I then pick the one with highest probability or something?

I dont think it is a good approach, but cannot find any articles explaining it.

I'd like to check, is it non-sense to have multiple models in multi-label case or not? If yes or no, why?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if they disagree on the label?

There are other ways of combining classifiers. For example, it's possible your labels display a natural hierarchy. A flight might either be delayed or not. If it is delayed, it might have a short delay or a long delay (which is an example you give); it it is not delayed, it might be on time or before time (another example you give).

Breaking down your multilabel classification into a hierarchy of problems might make sense in some case. The dataset sizes of a node's children might be very skewed. The misclassification costs might be hierarchical in nature. Along the way, this bypasses your problem of classifier disagreement.

See, for example [Multiple Model Approaches to Modelling and Control, by Roderick Murray-Smith and Tor Arne Johansen](http://folk.ntnu.no/torarnj/mmamc/mmamc_book.html?id=ansatte/Johansen_Tor.Arne/mmamc/mmamc_book.html), and [Combining Artificial Neural Nets, by Amanda J. C. Sharkey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.2383&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This is sometimes referred to as *modular classifier combination*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look at the papers. So I take it, it is possible to have nested models like this, they just need to be hieararchy kind of type, right?

Comment: @JanSila Yes. Of course, these approaches work better when the hierarchy is natural and inherent to the problem (which seems plausible in your case).

Comment: @JanSila You're welcome. All the best.